# HashMap cant be initialized with loop? Initialize HashMap from textfile

Tags: java, file, hashmap

I am a beginner at java and I'm trying to understand how HashMaps works. I want to use this for my talk bot so it can recognize e.g what the user is questioning:

For Example,
the key(String) is the category of what the user is questioning and the value(List<String>) is the questions the bot will look for.

My question is, when I look at my output in console it looks like it works but when I call the map.getKey() I don't get what I expect.

I am using Java 1.8 if it helps.

I have a text file with the content:
"!" is the category

```
!first!
1good
1hello
1bye
!second!
2good
2hello
2bye
```

This is my test class file with the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InitHash
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data.txt");

        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        try
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            String key = "";
            List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (scan.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = scan.nextLine();

                if (line.contains("!"))
                {
                    key = line;
                    key = key.replaceAll("!", "");
                    value.clear();
                } else
                {
                    value.add(line);
                }
                
                System.out.println(key + " , " + value);
                
                map.put(key, value);
            }
            
            scan.close();
            
            System.out.println(map.get("first")); //This prints the second category
            System.out.println(map.get("second"));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my output in console:

```
first , []
first , [1good]
first , [1good, 1hello]
first , [1good, 1hello, 1bye]
second , []
second , [2good]
second , [2good, 2hello]
second , [2good, 2hello, 2bye]
[2good, 2hello, 2bye] //This is suppose to output [1good, 1hello, 1bye]
[2good, 2hello, 2bye]
```

Any help and explanation is appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each entry in the map should be using a unique instance of `List`, otherwise, all the keys are sharing the same instance of the `List`. I also consider only putting the list in the map when the key has been considered to have changed

Comment: Do you mean I have to create two Lists? I tried to put the list in the map when the key changes but then the "first" key return null. Maybe I'm getting this all wrong. Sorry my english isn't at its best.

Comment: Check the posted example.  You should only have a single instance of `ArrayList`, but each time the key changes, you should create a new instance (and assign it to `values`) so new values can be added to it

Comment: Now I get it! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should be using a new instance of `ArrayList` each time you determine the key has changed, otherwise you are simply re-using the same `ArrayList` for EVERY key

The following example demonstrates a modified version of your code, so that when the code detects a new key, and the previous key is not blank, it will map the `key` to the current instance of the `ArrayList`.

It will then create a new instance of an `ArrayList` and place all the preceeding values into it

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data.txt");
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);) {
    String key = "";
    List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();

        if (line.contains("!")) {
            if (!key.trim().isEmpty()) {
                map.put(key, value);
                System.out.println(key + " , " + value);
            }
            key = line;
            key = key.replaceAll("!", "");
            value = new ArrayList<String>();
        } else {
            value.add(line);
        }

    }
    if (!key.trim().isEmpty() && !value.isEmpty()) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    scan.close();

    System.out.println(map.get("first")); //This prints the second category
    System.out.println(map.get("second"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your loop, instead of this:

```
value.clear();
```

Initialize it whenever you find a new category, in order to not modify the previous value's contents (*as the memory address is shared for both key's lists, you are just duplicating the last category's value to all previous categories*). This will assign `value` a new address in where to add the elements:

`value = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 2):

Existing code may be rewritten to use Java 8 method [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to create a new instance of the `ArrayList` when a new key appears in a bit more concise way.

Also, it is better to use `try-with-resources` to ensure the scanner of the input file is closed automatically.

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
    String key = "";

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();

        if (line.contains("!")) {
            key = line.replace("!", "");
            map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<String>());
        } else {
            map.get(key).add(line);
        }
        
        System.out.println(key + " , " + map.get(key));
    }
    
    System.out.println(map.get("first")); //This prints the second category
    System.out.println(map.get("second"));
}
```

Output:

```
first , []
first , [1good]
first , [1good, 1hello]
first , [1good, 1hello, 1bye]
second , []
second , [2good]
second , [2good, 2hello]
second , [2good, 2hello, 2bye]
[1good, 1hello, 1bye]
[2good, 2hello, 2bye]
```